# Как можно проанализировать и снизить расход трафика от клиента?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, написал клиента который пересылает фото, видео и аудио файлы, но сейчас задумался о расходе трафика при отправке. Тестировал я его только на wi- fi и всё нормально, но вот работа с мобильными сетями и заставляет задуматься. Подскажите какими средствами можно посмотреть его расход и соответственно снизить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проанализировать расход можно используя, например [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)

А вот снижать можно разными путями. Например, можно сжимать файлы перед отправкой. Например использовать [это](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor)